# How to reduce size of backgroundView of UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image: TableView with excess backgroundView]

I have 3 tableViews. There a subviews of main view. Any clue how to remove excessive background view border around each table? That's, for Label 2, there is bit of blank space after cell:7. I could hide it by

```
[tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
```

But I need to reset the size so that it appears close to cell. tableView.frame is same size as tableView.backgroundView.frame.

Comment: May I know the reason behind using three tableviews instead of using single tableview with three section with custom section header view.

Comment: Agree with imthi. You should implement using 1 tableview.